# How does SharePoint App Part resize work?

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app

I know how to resize SharePoint App Part dynamically. But I met a problem that it fails to resize for a particular App Part. So I debuged and found the SharePoint built-in code:

```
var widthCssText = "";
var resizeWidth = ('False' == spAppIFrameSenderInfo[senderIndex][3]);
if (resizeWidth)
{
    widthCssText = 'width:' + width + ' !important;';
}

var cssText = widthCssText;
var resizeHeight = ('False' == spAppIFrameSenderInfo[senderIndex][4]);
if (resizeHeight)
{
    cssText += 'height:' + height + ' !important';
}

if (cssText != "")
{
    // Resize it
}
```

Normally `spAppIFrameSenderInfo[senderIndex][3]` and `spAppIFrameSenderInfo[senderIndex][4]` are `'False'`, so `cssText` is not empty, but for that particular App Part, both `spAppIFrameSenderInfo[senderIndex][3]` and `spAppIFrameSenderInfo[senderIndex][4]` are `'True'`, so it won't resize.

But if I create one or more new App Part, the issue doesn't exist, when is `spAppIFrameSenderInfo[senderIndex][3]` or `spAppIFrameSenderInfo[senderIndex][4]` set to `'True'`? What's the logic behind it?

I am testing on SharePoint Online. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue anymore. It turns out we set fixed width and height in Web Part Appearance setting.